# Onenote - Hot key for going back to default font

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, copy-paste, text-editing, microsoft-onenote

I was editing a note in MS OneNote. I had written 5 lines using default styling and font. Then, I pasted a line from a webpage. The line was green in color with grey background. OneNote was able to show the line in the same green with grey background styling.

But, when I started typing further, all the text I typed also was green with grey background. Also, the default font was calibri. Now, it became Courier.

Is there a hotkey in OneNote which will simply reset the font and style configuration to default, so I don't have to laboriously reconfigure the text properties every time I copy something from a webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a hotkey in OneNote which will reset the font/style configuration to default?

You will have to select some text first, but then you can use the following shortcut:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - Apply the Normal style

Source [OneNote 2016 Shortcuts](https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/OneNote_2016.html)